# Arrange labels on a map so that they don't overlap

Tags: android, algorithm, drawing

In my (Android) App I am displaying a map with some labeled objects on it. When the objects are very close to each other, the labels overlap, as in this example picture (the bottom three objects):

[image: Example of overlapping labels]

I would like to display the labels with a line that points to their position, as for example here:

[image: Non-overlapping labels]

However, I can't think of an efficient algorithm, that calculates the required angles of the lines so that none of the labels overlap. The map is also zoomable while the label size does not change; Hence, the required angles will change with zoom level.

Is there any algorithm with not so high computational costs (i.e., where I don't need to calculate collisions between all the objects at every frame) that could help me here? Or should I precalculate something and ship it with the app? (The objects are always fixed)

Comment: Looks like a lot of work there. I'd just use a marker cluster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. That actually is a nice idea. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Use a spatial partitioning data structure (k-D tree, quadtree) for collision detection. This will avoid the brute force collision computations.
2. Combine 1. with a simple greedy strategy (for efficiency): Sort labels by priority (major cities first for instance). For each label that should be displayed, try multiple positions (left, right, top, bottom side of the bullet for instance) and pick the first one working if any (and render the label).
3. For labels whose reference points (the bullet) are spatially very close at the current zoom level: Do a first pass for the bullets only (collision detection and possibly rendering). Using 1. it should be possible to detect the bullets that are close to each other and prepare a pseudo label that will group all the text labels of the bullets together (with the desired type of line-based layout) and could be used (with some variations like horizontal or vertical grouping) with the collision detection + rendering pass of 2.

With this approach, the angles between the lines are actually not adjusted to avoid collision. Instead the computation is done to avoid overlap within the labels of the group and combined with the typical collision detection to avoid overlap with other labels.

Comment: Since you also mention some kind of marker cluster, I'll mark this as answered. Thank you for the other suggestions, I'll play around with them.